# Azure Devops Server 2022 - Adding a pick-list of users to a work item type

Tags: azure-devops, customization, tfs-workitem

We are using on-prem Devops Server 2022.  This is a system that has been regularly upgraded since first implemented as TFS 2010.

We wish to modify the "Feature" work item type to include a pick-list of users.  This field will represent the "Business Owner" of the feature and it will be a reportable field.

However, there does not appear to be a way to add a field for picking a user without stepping on an existing field.  For instance, there are these existing System fields:

- System.AssignedTo
- System.ChangedBy
- System.CreatedBy

What I need is a generic system user list that I can assign to the field via pick list.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we have the XML process model due to the age of our system.

For the user pick list, I wanted the list of DevOps valid users, not a custom hard-coded list in the GlobalList.

After experimenting and breaking some things in my non-production Azure DevOps, I found what to do.

To start, the many resources online are good general references, but of little specific help for adding fields.  I found no reference to the list and purpose of XML attributes for work item types.

After exporting the work item XML, I added a new field at the top using an existing user field as a pattern.  The key is specifying a `refname` for the field. In my case, I simply used the collection name and the field name.
For example: `refname="DefaultCollection.BusinessOwner"`

The complete field definition is:

```
<FIELD name="Business Owner" refname="DefaultCollction.BusinessOwner" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension">
    <HELPTEXT>This is the Business Sponsor most responsible for success of the project.</HELPTEXT>
    <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
    <VALIDUSER />
  </FIELD>
```

The attribute that allows using DevOps users for the picklist is `<VALIDUSER />`

I wanted this field to appear in web form with the Planning and Classification groups and to include a descriptive label. Down in the `<WebLayout>` section of the XML, I added a new Group block above the Planning and Classification group blocks:

```
<Group Label="Business Owner">
    <Control Type="LabelControl" Name="DefaultCollction.BusinessOwnerLabel" >
        <LabelText>
            <Text>Business Owner is the sponsor or resource planning designate for the project or feature.</Text>
        </LabelText>
    </Control>
    <Control Type="FieldControl" FieldName="DefaultCollction.BusinessOwner" />
</Group>
```

After importing the revised WIT XML, the new field appeared as I wanted it.  And it's reportable - I can select this field in queries and backlogs.

[Revised Feature Work Item with new Business User field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fnb7u.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Per your description it appears that that you are using the On-premises XML process model (upgraded from TFS 2010).

> What I need is a generic system user list that I can assign to the
> field via pick list.

You can try to create a global list file and add all `Business Owner` users into the list. Then use the global list in the `Business Owner` field definition. See [Define global lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/reference/xml/define-global-lists?view=tfs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops).

1.Create a new XML file named `GlobalList.xml`, open it in a text editor, and add the following:

```
<GLOBALLISTS>
 <GLOBALLIST  name="BusinessOwner">
  <LISTITEM value="UserName1" />
  <LISTITEM value="UserName2" />
  <LISTITEM value="UserName3" />
 </GLOBALLIST>
</GLOBALLISTS>
```

2.This Global List can be imported using the following command line (see [witAdmin: Customize and manage objects for tracking work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/witadmin/witadmin-customize-and-manage-objects-for-tracking-work?view=azure-devops) for details.):

```
Witadmin  importgloballist /collection:http://serverurl /f:GlobalList.xml
```

3.Once the Global List is successfully imported, we can modify the `Feature` WITD to use this Global List for the `Business Owner` field. In the field definition, change the `ALLOWEDVALUES` tag to the following:

```
 <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
       <GLOBALLIST  name="BusinessOwner" />
 </ALLOWEDVALUES>
```